# How can I make a timeout command in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I've been attempting to make a timeout command for the past 2 hours. I have found nothing that helps me, and I came over to stack overflow for some help.

Here is my attempt

```
@bot.command()
async def timeout(ctx,mem: discord.Member,ender:int):
    if ctx.author.id == myid:
        handover = await mem.edit(timed_out_until=datetime.timedelta(minutes=ender))
        if not handover:
            print('no')
```

I have been searching through the discord.py documents and all I found was timed_out_until

```
timed_out_until (Optional[datetime.datetime]) –

The date the member’s timeout should expire, or None to remove the timeout. This must be a timezone-aware datetime object. Consider using utils.utcnow().
```

I followed the way on using it, and my error text "no" is showing up. Can any of you guys help me?

Answer (score 1):

In your stage, there was no timeout.
But now, installing the new version of discord.py (v2.0) using

```
pip install git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
```

And there is a user.timeout :)
Hope it helps!

Documentation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=timeout#discord.Member.timeout

```
user.timeout(time, reason)
```